# Filter on array of objects, and foreach over second array for conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-5

I've hit a snag after a few hours -- wondered if a fresh minded developer can just review the below, the code is simplied to show the problem.

I am filtering a property value on an array of objects, and cross referencing that property with an array which has matching keys, and boolean values to control if it should be factored into the filter.

However my result is returning all 3 objects, despite the console.log seeming to evaluate correctly. Any ideas?

Many thanks...

```
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "status": "new",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "status": "rejected",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "status": "changed",
  }
];

var filter = {
  "new": true,
  "rejected": false,
  "changed": true
}

var result = data.filter(function(item) {
  var arr = [];

  Object.keys(filter).forEach(function(key) {
    if (item.status === key && filter[key] === true) {

      console.log('---')
      console.log('item.status', item.status)
      console.log('key', key)
      console.log('filter[key]', filter[key])
      console.log('---')

      arr.push(item);
    }
  });

  return arr;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this a bit more complicated than you need to. The function passed to `filter()` should return a boolean — you're returning an array.

You can simply filter with the lookup on the `filter` array, which will either return `false` or `undefined`, in which case you filter it out, or `true`, in which case you keep it..

```js
var data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "status": "new",
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "status": "rejected",
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "status": "changed",
  }
];

var filter = {
  "new": true,
  "rejected": false,
  "changed": true
}

var result = data.filter(item => filter[item.status])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You `filter` by returning something truthy or falsey directly, not by returning anything more specific (like an object). You can simplify your code to a one-liner:

```js
var data=[{"id":1,"status":"new",},{"id":2,"status":"rejected",},{"id":3,"status":"changed",}]
var filter = {
  "new": true,
  "rejected": false,
  "changed": true
}

var result = data.filter((item) => filter[item.status])
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`filter` will create a new array with every `item` that returned a truthy value. This should work:

```
var result = data.filter(function(item) {
  return filter[item.status];
});
```